# HTACCESS Redirection from www.url.com to www.url.com/home

Tags: .htaccess

I am using following htaccess file to achieve some redirections etc:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.myurl.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^$ /home [R=301,L]
```

Lately i ve added the latest line so when user visits https://www.myurl.com he gets redirected to https://www.myurl.com/home for the homepage. This works fine as wanted but i have a bad feeling that this should be written somehow better. I don't like the ^$ part but it works. How could i rewrite this?

Comment: Did you move all files from the root directory `/` to the `/home/` directory?

Comment: No. It's an MVC php webpage.

Comment: So `/index.php` is the old homepage and redirects to `/home/` but you want all of the other folders to still go where they are expected (eg `/contact/`)?

Comment: Yes, correct. www.url.com/index.php/sth goes to www.url.com/sth and www.url.com goes to www.url.com/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTPS` part can definitely be rewritten and should come first as you're creating multiple redirects.

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase /

#redirect all traffic looking for a domain not starting with www &
#all non-https traffic to the https://www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#This condition is better for analytics tracking and SEO (single subdns)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^$ home [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Since your MVC is likely using index.php to process all requests it's likely that the redirect to `/home` will not work unless you're visiting the website without requesting any file (the root only). If someone explicitly requests `https://www.myurl.com/index.php` your rule that says `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` tells the site to not change anything. Since you said this is working as expected I've not changed the order.

If it doesn't work as intended, then switch the order of the rule for `/home`.

```
RewriteRule ^$ home [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Great answer i ll use it for sure.